# How can I disable or remove a Magento 2 UI Global Component such as the modal?

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent

I want remove the Modal Ajax requests on every page - this is a Magento 2 UI componenet.

I tried this in my **app/design/frontend/scorpion/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<item name="Modal" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I also applied a query to remove authentication popup which works partially but it does not remove the modal calls..

```
<referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
```

However the files still do the AJAX request and still appear in HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the authentication pop-up loads the modal component on each page. Try to remove it (if it is not used):

```
<referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: I already tried that and it works 20%, that only removes the popup. It does not remove the modal-slide, modal-custom and modal-popup calls..

Comment: Any updates? You managed to find the solution